# Monitoring Voice in my android app

Tags: java, android, monitoring, voice

Iam making an android app which monitor voice in which when the voice loudness exceed a user defined threshold the app dial a specific number .

i done making voice monitoring and compared the highest value with the threshold then dialling the number .everything goes right except when the app returned after the call i find the  monitoring isnt right , as the mic sensitivity is very week (measurement is very low ) i have to restart the app to obtain the right measurement , the second question here i make the comparison of the threshold and the last value of sound in the handler at the bottom , is this the right way ?  thanks in advance[This is the App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66YHC.png)

Below is The Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final int sampleRate = 11025;
private static final int bufferSizeFactor = 10;
private Button Stop;
private ProgressBar On;
private Button Start;
private AudioRecord audio;
private int bufferSize;
private ProgressBar level;
private TextView textView;
volatile int threshold;
TextView testtextview;
private boolean clicked ;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private int lastLevel = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    threshold = 20000;
    //progressbar detect voice
    level = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_level);
    level.setMax(32676);
    //text displaying progress par value
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    testtextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewtest);

    if (audio != null) {

        audio.stop();
        audio.release();
        audio = null;
        handler.removeCallbacks(update);
    } else {
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * bufferSizeFactor;
        audio = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
        audio.startRecording();
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    readAudioBuffer();
                }

            });

            thread.setPriority(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getMaxPriority());
            thread.start();

        handler.removeCallbacks(update);
        handler.postDelayed(update, 25);
    }


    //seekbar let user choose threshhold
    SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    //text displayin user choice
    final TextView textViewuser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            textViewuser.setText("" + i + "/32676");
            threshold = i ;
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });


    Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dummy_buttonstop);
    On = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar11);
    Start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dummy_button);
    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            On.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            clicked = true;



        }
    });

    Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            On.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            clicked = false;
        }
    });




}



private void readAudioBuffer() {

    try {
        short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];

        int bufferReadResult;

        do {

            bufferReadResult = audio.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {

                if (buffer[i] > lastLevel) {
                    lastLevel = buffer[i];
                }

            }

        }
        while (bufferReadResult > 0 && audio.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING);

        if (audio != null) {
            audio.release();
            audio = null;
            handler.removeCallbacks(update);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private Runnable update = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        MainActivity.this.level.setProgress(lastLevel);
        textView.setText(lastLevel + "/" + level.getMax());
        if (clicked) {
            if (lastLevel > threshold) {
                clicked=false;
                Start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                On.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String url = "tel:01224271138";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);

                //recreate();

            }
        }

        lastLevel *= .5;
        handler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 500);







    }

};
```